# Existence of a subsequence and analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\{f_{n}\} _n{_\in \mathbb{_N}}$ be a sequence of functions which are analytic on the open
>   unit disc $D$ and such that $|f_{n}(z)| ≤ 1$ for all $n $ and all $z ∈ D$. Prove that there
>   is a subsequence$\{f_{n}{_j}\}$ and an analytic function $f$ on $D$ satisfying the following
>   property:
>
> For every $r$,  $0 < r < 1, max_{|z|≤r} |f(z) −f_{n}{_j}(z)| → 0 $ as $n_{j} → ∞$

Show by example that it is false in general that $sup_{z∈D} |f(z) − f_{n}{_j}(z| → 0$ as $n_{j} → ∞$.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The first part comes from  a basic theorem on normal families which can be found in any book on Complex Analysis. For the second part take $f_n(z)=z^{n}$. Use the fact that $(1-\frac  1 {n_k})^{n_k} \to \frac 1  e$ to see that the convergence is not uniform on $D$.

Comment: What's the name of that theorem? the only thing I know for normal families is it's definition!!

Comment: It is called Montel's Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem

Comment: @Math1 Boundedness implies that $(f_n)$ is a normal family. Hence a  subsequence converging uniformly on compact sets exists. Since $\{x: |z| \leq r\}$ is a compact set for each $r <1$ the convergence is uniform for $|z| \leq r$.

Comment: aha...and the max goes to zero because of the uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @Math1