# Subsequence of normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I have the following problem about normal families:

Let $A(\Omega)$ be the set of all analytic function in $\Omega$.

> Is it true that if $\{f_{n}\} _n{_\in \mathbb{_N}} ⊂ A(Ω)$ is normal, then for some sequence $\{m_{n}\} _n{_\in \mathbb{_N}}$, $ m_{n}→ ∞ $ a subsequence $\{f^{m_{n}}_{n}\} _n{_\in \mathbb{_N}} $ is normal.

I'm not sure, I think it's not true because  the boundedness may not preserved...but I don't have an example or a good explanation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take the original family just one function $f_n(z)= z, n=1,...$ on the unit disc so $z^n \to 0$ normally and you can choose $m_n=n$; on the other hand if you take something like $f_n(z)=2z, n=1,...$ on the unit disc, $(2z)^{m_n}$ has no normally convergent subsequence on the unit disc for any $m_n \to \infty$

Comment: so the statement not true in general because of boundedness@Conard

Comment: It depends on the normal family - it is definitely not true for all such, but it may be true for some

Comment: Thank you...can you help me in the second part of this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640837/existence-of-a-subsequence-and-analytic-function...

Comment: Is it mean that if I take the subsequence $(1-\frac  z {n_k})^{n_k} $ the supremum will not converges to $0$ ??

Comment: No it means that no subsequence of $f_n(z)=z^n$ converges uniformly (to zero) on $\mathbb D$ by showing that $\sup_{|z|=1-\frac{1}{n}}|f_n(z)| \ge C >0$ - note that $n$ is the same in both supremum and $f_n$ - this is essential as the sequence converges uniformly to zero on compact sets, counterxamples to uniform convergence to zero on the whole disc are of this type if they exist like here

Comment: And this not contradicts the first part of the question?

Comment: no because the first part is for compact sets within the unit disc - so in the above, for every $0<r<1$ there is a $n(r)$ for which $1-1/n >r$ hence on that circle we are out of $|z| \le r$ and the supremum result above has nothing to do with what happens in $|z| \le r$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help